# Time Delay for Accepting Answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I recently discovered that while trying to accept an answer, it said "You can accept an answer in 7 minutes".

Why is there this delay?

Answer (score 7):

There's a delay for accepting an answer because there's an excellent chance waiting a bit longer than just for the [FGITW answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533) to show up means there's a *better* answer to accept.
Or at least one of those has been improved from "just maybe adequate" to "good" or even "excellent".
Also, it gives the community at least a chance to show the fatal flaw (if any) which wasn't obvious without deeper knowledge and/or analysis.

For the same reason (though more so), there's an even longer wait before one can accept ones own answer: Question and answer can actually be posted at the same time!

Comment: Alright. That seems like a good explanation.